The continuity of $L^p$ norm of continuous bounded functions
Let $a\in (0,1)$, $1<a p<\infty$, and let $\Omega$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose that $f$ is continuous with compact support on $\Omega$. We know from the dominated convergence theorem that
$$\|f(\cdot+t)-f\|_{L^{p}(\Omega)}\rightarrow 0,$$
when $t\rightarrow 0$. Is it true that
$$\sup_{t>0} t^{-a} \|f(\cdot+t)-f\|_{L^{p}(\Omega)}\leq C \|f\|_{L^{\infty}(\Omega)},\tag{1}$$
for some constant $C>0$ independent of $f$.

I believe $(1)$ is kind of trivial if $f$ has a bounded derivative:
If we assume that $f$ is differentiable on $\Omega$, we have that $F(t)= |f(x+t)-f(x)|^{p}$ is differentiable at $t=0$, for $p>1$, with
$$F^{\prime}(0)=\bigg[p|f(x+t)-f(x)|^{p-2}(f(x+t)-f(x))f^{\prime}(x+t)\bigg]_{t=0}=0,$$
provided that the derivative $f^{\prime}$ is bounded on $\Omega$. That is
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow 0} t^{-1}F(t)=0.$$
So, if $f$ is continuously differentiable, it follows from dominated convergence that
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow 0} t^{-1} \|f(\cdot+t)-f\|_{L^{p}(\Omega)}=0.$$

The question is:
Does $(1)$ hold true with no differentiability assumption on $f$ ?

Interesting question.  What is $u$ and how is it used?  I only see $u$ mentioned once.

Also, what is $C$? Do you mean “there exists a $C>0$ such that..”?

I'm not sure.  I have a counterexample showing that $\sup_{t>0} t^{-a+1} ||f(\cdot +t)-f||_p = \infty$.

Choose $b>0$ such that $1<b<ap$.  Define $f(x)=x^{b-1}\sin{(\frac{1}{x})}$ for $x>0$ and $f(0)=0$.  This function is continuous on $[0,1]$.  It oscillates infinitely often as you approach zero from the right.  Problematic $t$'s are values which cause the period to shift by $\frac{\pi}{2}$.  This counterexample might work if $a$ is close to zero, but I don't think it works since $ap>1$.

There might be a counterexample for sufficiently large $p$.  I think I need to choose $b$ such that $1<b<a+1-\frac{2}{p}$.  I'll try to write it up.

I posted a counterexample using a single function.  Not only is there no constant $C$ that works for all continuous functions, there is no constant that works for a single continuous function given those conditions.

This is not true in general for any $a>0$ and $1\leq p<\infty$. Consider $L^p[0,1]$, and define a sequence of "continuous spike" functions $(f_{n})\in L^p[0,1]$ defined by, $f_n=0$ if $n$ is odd, and if $n$ is even,
$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases} 2nx&\text{if}~0\leq x\leq\frac{1}{2n}\\
-2nx+2(2k+1) &\text{if}~\frac{4k+1}{2n}< x< \frac{4k+3}{2n}~\text{for}~k\in\{0,\dots,(n-2)/2\}\\
2nx-4k &\text{if}~\frac{4k-1}{2n}\leq x\leq\frac{4k+1}{2n}\text{for} k\in\{1,\dots,n/2\}.
\end{cases}$$
Therefore, for even $n$ and $t_n= 2/n$,
$$\|f_n(\cdot+t_n)-f_n\|_p=\left (\frac{2p}{p+1}\right)^{1/p},$$
so
$$\sup_{t>0}t^{-a}\|f_n(\cdot+t)-f_n\|_p\geq (2n)^{a}\left(\frac{2p}{p+1}\right)^{1/p},$$
whereas $\|f_n\|_\infty=1$. Thus, for all even $n$ and any $C>0$
$$\sup_{t>0}\|f_n(\cdot+t)-f_n\|_p-C\|f_n\|_\infty\geq  (2n)^{a}\left(\frac{2p}{p+1}\right)^{1/p}-C,$$
which converges to infinity for any $a>0$.
To answer your further question in the comment, if $f$ is continuously differentiable on $[a,b]$, then it is Lispchitz with constant $K\geq 0$. Thus, for any $t>0$,
$$\|f(\cdot+t)-f\|_p=\left(\int_{a}^{b}|f(t+x)-f(x)|^pdx\right)^{1/p}\leq \left(\int_{a}^{b}|Kt|^pdx\right)^{1/p}.$$
Therefore
$$\lim_{t\to 0^+}t^{-\alpha}\|f(\cdot+t)-f\|_p\leq\lim_{t\to 0^+}t^{1-\alpha}K(b-a)^{1/p}=0.$$

@Medo No I don't think so, just take $L^p[0,2\pi]$ and $f(x)=\sin(x)$. It's continuously differentiable, and $|f(\cdot+\pi)-f|_p\geq1$, so the suprememum is bounded below by $\pi^{-a}$.

But you agree that if $f$ is continuously differentiable on $[a,b]$, then $\lim_{t\to 0} t^{-1}{|f(\cdot+t)-f|_{L^{p}([a,b])}}=0$ ?

@Medo Yes indeed, see my edit.

Theorem: For any $p>1$ and $a\in (0,1)$ satisfying $ap>1$, there exists a continuous real-valued function on $[0,1]$ such that
$$\sup_{t>0} t^{-a} ||f(\cdot +t) - f||_p = \infty . $$
Proof: Choose $b>0$ such that $b<\frac{2}{p}(ap-1)$.  Define the following function:
$$f(x) = x^{b} \sin{(\frac{1}{x})}\ \ \mbox{for}\ x>0,$$
and $f(0)=0$.  Clearly, $f$ is continuous on the interval $[0,1]$.  Given a natural number $n$, define $t_n$ as
$$t_n = \frac{1}{2n\pi (4n-1)} .$$
This value satisfies the equation
$$\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2n\pi}+t_n} = 2n\pi - \frac{\pi}{2} .$$
Thus, there exists a constant $k_0 >0$ such that
$$\int_{\frac{1}{2(n+1)\pi}}^{\frac{1}{2n\pi}}
|(x+t_n)^{b}\sin{(\frac{1}{x+t_n})} - x^{b}\sin{(\frac{1}{x})} |^p d\mu > 
\frac{k_0}{n^2 n^{bp}}.\tag{*} $$
The square comes into play because the length of the interval is
$$\frac{1}{2n\pi} - \frac{1}{2(n+1)\pi} = \frac{1}{2n(n+1)\pi} .$$
Hence,
$$||f(\cdot +t_n)-f||_p > \Big( \frac{k_0}{n^2} \Big)^{\frac{1}{p}} \frac{1}{n^{b}}. $$
Since $t_n$ is on the order of $\frac{1}{n^2}$, there exists a constant
$k_1>0$ such that
$$t_n^{-a}||f(\cdot +t_n)-f||_p > k_1 n^{2a} n^{\frac{-2}{p}} n^{-b} 
= k_1 n^{2a-\frac{2}{p}-b}. $$
Since $b<\frac{2}{p}(ap-1)$, then $2a-\frac{2}{p}-b>0$ and
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} t_n^{-a}||f(\cdot +t_n)-f||_p = \infty .$$

Good catch.  I edited to reflect your correction.

Yes, the two functions have the same range. That doesn't imply the difference is small.  We're estimating the difference at each value of $$.  You have to use the fact that $\sin(\frac{1}{+_n})≈sin(\frac{1}{}−\frac{\pi}{2})=\cos(\frac{1}{x})$.  I'm pretty sure it's correct. We're estimating the difference at each $x$ in the interval which is bounded away from zero for most points. The phase is off by about $\frac{\pi}{2}$ for each value of $$.

$b$ is a parameter used to solve the problem.  It is not an extra condition.  I believe that my solution is more general, since it is a counterexample with a single function.  By the way, it is possible to modify the other solution and get a counterexample with only one function.  Essentially, I would be creating a function with infinitely many spikes whose heights gradually go to zero.  Anyway, I enjoyed working on your question.

I am sorry. I don't know why I confused $a$ with $b$. I meant to say the other answer dropped the condition $ap>1$. I learned a couple of nice tricks from your answer. The common theme and main point here is to use uniformly continuous functions that are not Lipschitz.
